# How to read AnonymousSubject in Angular 2

Tags: angular, debugging, typescript, rethinkdb

I'm currently debugging my ng2 application through console.logs. If you're logging an array, it will return an AnonymousSubject with the following attributes:

```
AnonymousSubject
_isScalar:false
closed:false
destination:AnonymousSubject
hasError:false
isStopped:false
observers:Array[0]
operator:ToArrayOperator
source:AnonymousSubject
thrownError:null
__proto__:Subject
```

Is it possible to see the contents of the array? Why does clicking 'destination' loop its content recursively n amount of times?

Code:

```
GetFeed(id: UUID): Feed[] {    
    var toReturnFeed: any[];

    this.table.find({id: id}).fetch().subscribe(result => toReturnFeed);
    console.log(toReturnFeed);

    return toReturnFeed;
}
```

I've got more questions but I'll save those for now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't tried to use as observable and subscribe ?

Comment: why do you want to read that? if you need to see the data that it handles you have to `subscribe` on it and call `console.log` inside the `subscribe`, or use `do` operator to simply log every time it will emit a new value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not logging an actual array, but an `Observable` which will probably return an array.

And because of the structure you constructed this `Observable`, its destination is the same as the origin, and will therefor have a cyclic reference.

To get the array logged:

```
this.someObservable.subscribe((someArray: any[]) => {
    console.log(someArray);
});
```

Now that you've posted your code you seem to be forgetting a important concept of `aync` methods. You cannot return `toReturnFeed` like that, because it will always result in `undefined`. You should return the `Observable<Feed[]>`

```
GetFeed(id: UUID): Observable<Feed[]> { 
    return this.table.find({id: id}).fetch()
}
```

You can then call this method from somewhere else and get the results like this:

```
serviceInstance.GetFeed(1).subscribe((returnFeed: Feed[]) => {
    console.log(returnFeed);
});
```

Comment: another way to log it would be to add a `do` operator, this way it'll be logged when something is emited from the observable. Thank you for the explanation on why it's cyclic, didn't know that.

Comment: @Supamiu so, `do` does not really initiate the `Observable` like `subscribe`, but adds an extra method you can perform (like `map`), while not altering the data?

Comment: that's exactly it yes, `do` allows you to put a readonly method inside your observable chain, without triggering it like subscribe. If you want to debug a http request, it might be useful.

Comment: @PierreDuc That makes sense but is still really confusing. I've added some code if you feel like clarifying a bit more?

Comment: Thanks Pierre, it works. Is there no way to simply fetch a record without bothering with subscribers and observers though?

Comment: Have a look at the `async` implementation of [`TypeScript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). But you need to add a `toPromise` to your observable then